# Hill Cipher - Unknown plaintext attack, known key

Tags: hill-cipher

I was wondering if I have the key and the encrypted Hill Cipher message(s). I can definitely figure out the charset involved. But the order is missing. Assuming that I use 37 modulo or higher. How would I go about cracking it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You just decrypt it. I can't think of a language that uses more than 36 letters apart from the Chinese family but then again I'm not a linguist.

Decrypt to a reasonable $n$ and then use the [character frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) to infer the language (and hence the modulo). Some trial and error may be required untill you get it right but for values of $n$ less than $2^{32}$ it shouldn't give you any practical problems on a desktop computer.

Comment: Assume the cipher uses digits and special characters, so it increases. Or the full ASCII set maybe. modulo 256+

Comment: Then start with max(modulo) and work your way down. It'll make sense at some point. You must have some notion of how the plaintext should look like so that you have something to compare your decryptions against.